# Injecting variable in DAO from controller

Tags: java, spring

I have DAO classes which are extending 'GenericDAO'

Generic dao has LanguageId variable with getter and setter.

I get my languageid from session.

Is there any way that I can set my language ID in `genericDAO` directly. So that every time i use dao class i dont have to pass languageId from my controller?

At last what i want is, I should be able to `getLanguageId()` in my dao object.

Answer (score 3):

Usually DAOs are set up as singletons, so there is only one instance that all the different threads use. If that is the case, then you can't set the language for one user without others possibly getting impacted, and passing it in as a method argument is the only safe way to make sure other threads don't inadvertently get the wrong language id. So whether you can do what you want depends on what scope your DAOs have.

Answer (score 0):

The very point of DAO is they're **stateless** while session represents some **stateful** information. All **stateful** information is supposed to be passed to DAOs via methods' arguments.

So, if you still want to have getLanguageId() in DAO, you are doomed to create DAO instance per each session and inject languageId to it during creation.